# Scatterplot set color and legend based on data point label for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a scatter plot and color the points with ID. And I want to make sure my legends displays all the IDs with respected colors. Here's my code:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2000)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 50, 2000)
ID = np.random.randint(0,100,2000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8),dpi = 80)
scatter = ax.scatter(x,
                     y,
                    c = ID)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(),
          loc="center left", 
          title='ID', 
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)
         )    
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x',labelrotation = 45)
```

But the legends only gives me a list of IDs with even interval instead of all the actual IDs used in the data.

[image: What I have:]

How do I set the correct legend so it displays ALL the IDs used in coloring the points? Thanks.

Comment: Please make a fake dataset.  You claim this is not putting the right IDs in the legend, but thats what the code says, so it seems that is what is in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matpotlib` is currently inferring you colors to be on a continuous scale instead of a categorical one.

You can pass the unique IDs you want a label to be created for into the `num` argument of `.legend_elements` to do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, 2000)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 50, 2000)
ID = np.random.randint(0,100,2000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8),dpi = 80)
scatter = ax.scatter(x,
                     y,
                    c = ID)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(num=list(np.unique(ID))),
          loc="center left", 
          title='ID', 
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
          ncol=5
         )    
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x',labelrotation = 45)
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can iterate over your unique IDs and add each a scatter for each unique ID. This way `matplotlib` will infer your IDs as unique entries on your plot.

You'll additionally need to segment a sequential colormap to achieve a non-repeating color and pair those colors against the unique IDs.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = rng.uniform(0, 100, 2000)
y = rng.uniform(0, 50, 2000)
ID = rng.integers(0,100,2000) 
unique_ids = np.unique(ID)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
cmap = get_cmap('viridis', len(unique_ids))

for _id, color in zip(unique_ids, cmap.colors):
    mask = (ID == _id)
    ax.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], label=_id, color=color)

ax.legend(ncol=5, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left', title='Tracker IDs')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much - I kept using *scatter.legend_elements(num=len(np.unique(ID))) and never thought to use list(). This is it!

Comment: Awesome, if this worked for you do you mind selecting this as the correct answer and upvoting so other users who have a similar question can quickly find the answer?

Comment: Definitely - I can only select this as the correct answer but I can't upvote due to me being a new account. But this is for sure a go-to answer for this type of question!

Comment: Just earned enough points to come and give the answer an upvote! Thanks again.